# Showing a Form from Presenter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvp

I have more of an architectural question. I'm trying to implement MVP in C# as follows:

- IView creates Presenter
- IPresenter has a property IView which holds View, that is bound to it
- View CAN be Form, but Presenter does not distinguish between Form and non-Form types, so View can be swapped and the solution is to be testable

What I sometimes need to do, is to open some other form. E.g., I have Browser view with DataGrid and when I double-click on a grid item or select something and click Edit button, Edit event is raised and Presenter acts.

Now, Presenter needs to open a Editor view, which is also a Form, *but* the problem is, presenter should not construct the Form itself, because then it is impossible to Mock the View.

I'm pretty struggling with the proper concept. My code looks something like this:

```
var editorView = new EditorForm();
editorView.Presenter.Entity = SelectedEntity;
editorView.ShowDialog(View as Form);
```

Under the hood, EditorForm constructor constructs the presenter and assigns *this* (View instance) to the presenter:

```
public EditorForm()
{
    Presenter = new EditorPresenter(this);
    InitializeComponents();
}
```

From the View perspective, I can swap it to MockView simply by implementing the Mock and then instantiating the same Presenter from MockView's constructor.

I was searching for some other Q&A here and over the web but did not find anything suitable.

Thank you for all your hints.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your conception,
I suggest you to project the Edit presentation issue according to MVP pattern as you did with main view.
So create IEditView and EditPresenter and finally in main presenter create instance of EditPresenter. Generally control the edit view through its presenter.

Comment: I don't think it will solve my problems, as I still will need to create a View - Form, so when testing, Presenter will contain instance of Form instead of MockView...

Comment: So if you would use Interface for EditView you will able to inject mock of EditView. Yo can do it during an init of a app, but then you need to reproject the parent view for init IEditView. Or you can init them by the container Ioc (Microsoft Unity).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is something I intend to do. But in my case, to use Spring.net to construct the View based on external configuration which will be different for production and for the test. I actually wrote that yesterday as a possible answer to my problem. I was just curious if there is some more clever solution than this one.

Answer (score 0):

After some brainstorming with some friends, we came to the conclusion, the best way to handle the case of instantiating different set of Views for production (FormViews) and different set for testing (MockViews) is constructing them in some context - in my case, Spring context is an option.

So far, I consider this as an answer for the problem. If you have some more clever solution, please feel free to share!